# There was no endpoint listening at

Tags: docusignapi

I have just started receiving the following message when trying to call the DocuSign web service:

"There was no endpoint listening at https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."

It was working perfectly earlier this morning and now we get this message consistently. We have not made any changes to the code that is calling the web service or the addresses that it uses.

I'm not sure if its a problem over at DocuSign or something at our end. Is anyone else experiencing the same issue?

Comment: Which SOAP call are you making when receiving this and are you still receiving this error?  It's definitely possible that a new release or service pack in the demo environment causes an error like this as I've seen examples of that before, usually it gets sorted out pretty quickly and never effects production (www) though...

Answer (score 0):

For production you can always check https://trust.docusign.com/ - it's a way to see how all the data centers are behaving NA1, NA2, EU1 and the rest.

It doesn't seem like there was a demo maintenance today.  It could be some sort of a firewall config somewhere between your app and our web services.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the responses. It is all working again now. I guess someone somewhere was fiddling with something because it just fixed its self somewhere around mid day.

Thanks again.